# Flex 4 - How to check NumericStepper value is NaN or not?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am using NumericStepper in my application. I want to check the NumericStepper is NaN or not? And I don't want to check like (!value). This is one of the restriction for my application. So I have to check exactly NumericStepper value is NaN or not.

Comment: _isNaN(value)_ or _value == NaN_

Comment: sorry. I can't understand.

Comment: use _isNaN_ function for checking if _value_ is _NaN_. My second solution will not work, I forgot that _NaN_ != _NaN_ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a isNaN function which checks exactly what you need.

Check here for more info:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000571.html

Comment: It's right. And thank you. Today I learnt the new function. I am a new one for flex. If you know any useful link about flex please share it. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check by "NaN" ...

NaN is Number Constant...so u can check your value...